# Constant acceleration in general relativity

Tags: general-relativity

How is constant acceleration expressed covariantly with 4-vectors ? The 4-acceleration cannot be constant along a worldline, because it's a tangent vector with a varying basepoint in spacetime. Is it rather that the 4-acceleration is the parallel transport of itself along the worldline ?

As a more concrete example, imagine a spaceship far from all masses, planets and stars. Its engines are turned off, so it's at rest. Then it fires them, ejecting some fuel to gain constant acceleration. The ship's crew experiences the acceleration as a fake gravity field directed towards the floor of the ship, they can feel it is constant.

In Newtonian physics, the ship at rest is a Galilean referential. When it fires its engines, its acceleration can then be measured as a 3-vector in that Galilean referential. Therefore, in the relativistic setting I expect 3 constant numbers, but I don't manage to define them.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Four-acceleration

Comment: @WillyBillyWilliams I'd read this page before posting my question. It only talks about constant 4-acceleration in a special relativity's inertial frame. I'm asking for constant acceleration in curved spacetime, without reference to a coordinate frame.

Comment: V. Semeria: "_I'm asking for constant acceleration in curved spacetime, without reference to a coordinate frame._" -- If [the Wikipedia secion concerning "non-inertial coordinates"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Four-acceleration#Four-acceleration_in_non-inertial_coordinates) does not satisfy you then, arguably, you should not ask for (constant) acceleration to be expressed in terms of 4-vectors at all (which may be considered depending on coordinates and a choice of coordinate basis expressed by index $\mu$), but instead for a manifestly coordinate-free expression. [... continued]

Comment: The magnitude of acceleration of a participant $P$ can be expressed in a general and manifestly coordinate-free way in terms of values of [Lorentzian distance $\ell$](https://www.google.com/#q=%22lorentzian+distance%22+beem+ehrlich+easley) between pairs of events in which $P$ took part; in particular, constant acceleration magnitude is for any three events $\varepsilon_{P A}$, $\varepsilon_{P B}$,  $\varepsilon_{P C}$ in which $P$ took part: [... continued]

Comment: $a=c \sqrt{\frac{\ell^4[\varepsilon_{P A}, \varepsilon_{P B}] + \ell^4[\varepsilon_{P A}, \varepsilon_{P C}] + \ell^4[\varepsilon_{P A}, \varepsilon_{P B}] - 2 \, \ell^2[\varepsilon_{P A}, \varepsilon_{P B}] \, \ell^2[\varepsilon_{P A}, \varepsilon_{P C}] - 2 \, \ell^2[\varepsilon_{P A}, \varepsilon_{P B}] \, \ell^2[\varepsilon_{P B}, \varepsilon_{P C}] - 2 \, \ell^2[\varepsilon_{P A}, \varepsilon_{P C}] \, \ell^2[\varepsilon_{P B}, \varepsilon_{P C}]}{\ell^2[\varepsilon_{P A}, \varepsilon_{P B}] \, \ell^2[\varepsilon_{P A}, \varepsilon_{P C}] \, \ell^2[\varepsilon_{P B}, \varepsilon_{PC}]}}.$

Comment: Be warned that user12262 generally holds very unorthodox views.

Comment: V. Semeria: Since user @0celouvskyopoulo7 has expressed doubts (to you) about the suggestion I made in the comment above, I've (nevertheless) been prompted to double-check this; considering simple cases in flat regions, such as circular motion, or hyperbolic/uniform acceleration. I find that **my suggestion is in general incorrect; sorry**. Indeed, it doesn't even seem to hold in the limit that the values of (square of) Lorentzian $\ell^2$ (or in the flat case: interval values $s^2$) are approaching Zero. (It may take a few weeks to review this to my own satisfaction. I hope to report back.)